# How to use bdl package in R

Tags: r, package, installation

I'm trying to use BDL package in R (https://github.com/statisticspoland/R_Package_to_API_BDL) but it doesn't work.

I followed instructions in GitHub:
https://github.com/statisticspoland/R_Package_to_API_BDL

```
install.packages('C:/Users/FILE/bdl_1.0.0.zip', repos = NULL, type="source")
library(bdl)
```

I got errors:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bdl’ in rbind(info,
>   getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):  number of columns of matrices
>   must match (see arg 2)

I don't know how to deal with it.